# Join by location on Qgis when target layer has multiple layer

Tags: qgis

I posted here a while ago about spatial joins. I have a huge dataset (20,000?) of bird and mammal ranges.
I have another dataset of all the countries.

In qgis, I was attempting to link the two shapefiles so that I could make a dataset containing all the countries the animals live in.

I thought I had it sorted with 'join by location' on qgis, but I realised if the animals range was in more than one country, it only saved the first country.

Can anyone tell me how I could do this differently so that I can get all the countries, not just the first?

Edited:both datasets are shapefiles.

Comment: Are the animal ranges given as polygons?

Comment: Do you want the results to be lists (in an attribute) of all the countries overlapped by the animal ranges?

Comment: @user24420, looking at your comments in the answers given below, we need some clarification as to what you are _expecting_ to get, and what kinds of vectors you are dealing with.

Answer (score 2):

intersect should return a polygon layer with a polygon each bird and the country it lives in.
[image: intersect]
[image: order]
Your new polygon layer will have a record for each bird and each country.
run polygon centroid on your intersect layer.
[image: centroid]
Install the groupstats plugin.
[image: plugininstaller]
setup your groupstats with column names and values
[image: groupstats]
Edit the csv in a a text editor to get the field names in the first row.
Add the csv back into your project.
join the csv to the courtries polygon with the country name as the join field.

Comment: I think I've confused myself a bit. I ran this method on a small sample of data. When I just do intersect it appears to create a row for every new country the animal lives in. So if one animal shapefile is in 2 countries I get 2 rows of data, each with one country. I'm not sure what join by location would do? I feel like I might be missing something. LAst time I thought i had it right and wasted a week running a massive dataset...

Comment: UnderDark asked for clarification. it is still not clear if you have a polygon and a point file, or 2 polygon files.

Comment: They're both polygons I think?

Comment: @user24420 "IF" you have 1 polygon bird layer and 1 polygon country layer. then follow new edits

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to just run the v.overlay GRASS command within QGIS commander.  This option will introduce you to the many powerful GRASS vector and raster commands that you may use within QGIS.

1. Go to Plugin menu and enable the GRASS plugin
2. On the Processing menu select Commander
3. Type in `v.overlay` and click enter on your keyboard.  This will open the v.overlay form.
4. Fill out the form and select run.

Join by Location is not needed!

Comment: Hi artwork, wahts the advantage of doing this way? Is it just faster?

Comment: @user24420, Yes, you only have to perform the one geoprocess (overlay), which does both intersect and join by location.  Also, as I stated in my answer it shows you how to access the various vector and raster processing GRASS commands that you may run within QGIS.

Comment: I think I've confused myself a bit. I ran the former method on a small sample of data. When I just do intersect it appears to create a row for every new country the animal lives in. So if one animal shapefile is in 2 countries I get 2 rows of data, each with one country. So maybe I don't need to do join by location anyway?